# How to make a parametrized module

Tags: module, racket

I know its kind of silly to start a question on Racket with "is it possible" (but here I go)

Is it possible to create a paramterized module similar to OCaml's functors?
Let's say I have the following structure

```
;;module A
(define x ...)

(provide foo)

(define (foo a) (format "x for foo: ~a ~a" x a))
(define (bar a) (format "x for bar: ~a ~a" x a))
```

then I define 2 other modules that use module As definitions

```
;;module B

(require "A.rkt" #| '(value for x is "lala") |# )

(define result1 (foo "lulu"))
(define result1 (bar "lili"))

;;result1 => "x for foo: lala lulu"
;;result2 => "x for bar: lala lili"
```

and

```
;;module C

(require "A.rkt" #| '(value for x is "empty") |# )

(define result1 (foo "really"))
(define result1 (bar "nothing"))

;;result1 => "x for foo: empty really"
;;result2 => "x for bar: empty nothing"
```

Obviously I could define foo and bar to have an additional parameter each, 
partially apply that additional param and define new funcs

```
;;module A2

(provide foo)

(define (foo x a) (format "x for foo: ~a ~a" x a))
(define (bar x a) (format "x for bar: ~a ~a" x a))
```

and then

```
;;module B2

(require "A2.rkt")

(define foo1 (partial foo "homemade"))
(define bar1 (partial bar "homemade"))

(define result1 (foo1 "really"))
(define result1 (bar1 "nothing"))

;;result1 => "x for foo: homemade really"
;;result2 => "x for bar: homemade nothing"
```

but that is really not what I want - rather I want to somehow preserve the module/require way and not have to redefine
the (almost same) functions over and over again.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: As asked, you want [units](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/units.html), which are extremely similar to ML functors. In practice, though, you can often get away with [parameters](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/parameterize.html) or other, simpler constructs, so units aren’t that commonly used in practice.

Comment: I read on parameters but I havent grokked them yet. Maybe you could write one of your super nice blog posts on it ;-) No seriously thanks for the pointer

Comment: I’d write a real answer, but right now, I need to go to sleep. ;) If someone else hasn’t by the time I get a chance, I’ll write something up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Alexis mentioned, the closest thing in Racket corresponding to ML functors is the [`unit`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/mzlib_unit.html) system. Here's one translation of your example (slightly simplified) into units.

First, define signatures for the interfaces between components:

```
(define-signature in^ (x))
(define-signature out^ (foo bar))
```

The `A` component takes in values for the `in^` bindings (just `x` here) and produces definitions for the `out^` bindings (`foo` and `bar`):

```
(define-unit A@
  (import in^)
  (export out^)
  (define (foo a) (format "x for foo: ~a ~a" x a))
  (define (bar a) (format "x for bar: ~a ~a" x a)))
```

The `B` component actually needs to be split into two parts: a unit that provides the definition of `x` and a unit that uses the `foo` and `bar` functions. I've simplified the latter part to just print out the results so I don't have to create another signature.

```
(define-unit B-in@
  (import)
  (export in^)
  (define x "lala"))

(define-unit B@
  (import out^)
  (export)
  (printf "~a\n" (foo "lulu"))
  (printf "~a\n" (bar "lili")))
```

In this example, the linkage can be inferred automatically from the signatures and unit definitions. To link these components together and run the result, you can just do this:

```
(invoke-unit/infer (link A@ B-in@ B@))
```

That's equivalent to invoking the following *compound unit* (similar to functor application), which can be written more explicitly like this:

```
(invoke-unit (compound-unit/infer (import) (export) (link A@ B-in@ B@)))
```

Instead of asking Racket to infer the linkage, you can also write it explicitly as follows:

```
(invoke-unit
 (compound-unit
   (import)
   (export)
   (link [((B-in : in^)) B-in@]
         [((A : out^)) A@ B-in]
         [() B@ A])))
```

Instead of creating an explicit unit to satisfy the `in^` import, you can also get the bindings from the context when you invoke the compound unit. For example:

```
(define-unit C@
  (import out^)
  (export)
  (printf "~a\n" (foo "really"))
  (printf "~a\n" (foo "nothing")))

(let ([x "empty"])   ;; the in^ bindings come from here!
  (invoke-unit
   (compound-unit/infer (import in^) (export) (link A@ C@))
   (import in^)))
```

Another important special form is `define-values/invoke-unit`, which takes a unit's exports and turns them into normal Racket definitions.

```
(let ([x "apple"])  ;; in in^ bindings come from here!
  (define-values/invoke-unit A@ (import in^) (export out^))
  ;; the out^ exports are available for the rest of the let body
  (foo "orange"))
```